Traceless stress-energy-momentum tensor of a real scalar field theory
I'm trying to compute the trace of the stress-energy-momentum (SEM) tensor of the simplest possible quantum field theory: a non-interacting massless real scalar field theory. The Lagrangian density is:
$$ L=(\partial_\mu\phi)^2=(\partial_t\phi)^2-(\nabla\phi)^2$$
in the $(1, -1, -1)$ metric. (I am in 3 spacetime dimensions although this is not important).
I find that the SEM tensor density is given by:
$$T^{\mu\nu}=2(\partial^\mu\phi)(\partial^\nu\phi)-\eta^{\mu\nu}L$$
The diagonal components read:
$$ T^{00}=H=(\partial_t\phi)^2+(\nabla \phi)^2$$
$$ T^{ii}=(\partial_t\phi)^2+(\partial_i\phi)^2-\sum_{j\neq i}(\partial_j\phi)^2$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian density. I now compute the trace. Using the formula for $T^{\mu\nu}$ computed above (and not the components), I find,
$$ T^\mu_\mu= -(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$$
However, when I add the diagonal components I computed above, I find,
$$ T^\mu_\mu=3(\partial_t\phi)^2+(\nabla\phi)^2$$
which is not the same as the previous expression.
I am unable to make sense of this. There is no scale in the problem so I expect the trace to be 0, which I can show using the first expression by integrating over spacetime, integrating by parts, and then using the equation of motion. Is the second expression wrong? Where have I made a mistake?
Also, if the first expression is correct, why was it necessary to use the equation of motion to show that the SEM tensor is traceless. Is this fact only an on-shell property then?

You should use Lorentz covariant notation. Also, most physicists would put a factor 1/2 in the Lagrangian. 'why was it necessary' you seem to be working with some textbook. Your metric tensor is 1+2 dimensional and this is important. You should ask your teacher.

Could you point out where I have not used Lorentz covariant notation and why the expressions do not match? The factor of 1/2 in the Lagrangian does not change the discrepancy I point out. I'm also not working with a specific textbook, but trying to understand better the SEM tensor.

Your second equation is the only one where you did.

I figured out what I was doing wrong. All the equations I have written are correct except the last one. There, I should not add the diagonal components but compute $T^{00}-T^{11}-T^{22}$, due to the metric. Then, both ways of doing the computation give the same answer.

The trace of the energy momentum tensor is not zero for the Lagrangian you chose. If you want a traceless tensor you must use
$$
S[\varphi,g]= \frac 12 \int d^nx \sqrt{g}\left( g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \varphi\partial_\nu\varphi  + \frac{(n-2)}{4(n-1)}R \varphi^2+m^2 \varphi^2\right)
$$
Apart from the $m^2$ term, this action is invariant under
$$
g_{\mu\nu}\to \tilde g_{\mu\nu}\,\,\,\,=\,\, \Omega^2(x) g_{\mu\nu}\nonumber\\
\varphi(x)\to \tilde\varphi(x)= \,\,\Omega^{(2-n)/2}(x)\varphi(x)\nonumber
$$
and we expect a conservation law from this symmetry.
Now the energy-momentum tensor is defined by
$$
\delta S[g, \varphi] = \frac 12 \int_m d^n x \sqrt{g} T_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$
and we can use the result
$$
g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu} =  (g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^2 -\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu) \delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$
(see M. Forger, H.Romer,  Currents and the Energy-Momentum Tensor in Classical Field Theory: A fresh look at an Old Problem, arXiv:hep-th/0307199)
to compute the contribution of the scalar curvature term  to the energy-momentum tensor as
$$
\delta \int d^nx \sqrt{g} {\textstyle \frac 12 }R \varphi^2\\= \frac 12  \int \sqrt{g} d^nx \left(\frac 12 g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}R\varphi^2 + \delta g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu} \varphi^2 + g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu} \varphi^2\right)\nonumber\\
=   \frac 12  \int d^nx \sqrt{g} \left( (g_{\mu\nu} \nabla^2 - \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu)\varphi^2 + (R_{\mu\nu}- {\textstyle \frac 12} g_{\mu\nu} R)\varphi^2\right) \delta g^{\mu\nu}\nonumber
$$
Using $\delta \sqrt{g}= - {\textstyle \frac 12}\sqrt{g}  g_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$  we find  the  usual energy momentum tensor
$$
T^{\rm old}_{\mu\nu}= \partial_\mu\varphi\partial_\nu\varphi- {\textstyle \frac 12} g_{\mu\nu} \left(g^{\alpha\beta} \partial_\alpha \varphi\partial_\beta \varphi +m^2 \varphi ^2\right)
$$
whose trace
$$
{T^\mu}_\mu =\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi- n/2(\left(\partial^\mu \varphi\partial_\mu \varphi +m^2 \varphi ^2\right)\\
=(1-n/2) \partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi - \frac n2 m^2 \varphi^2,
$$
is zero when $m^2=0$ only in $n=2$ space-time dimensions.
If to this  this we  the contributions from the scalar curvature term
$$
T^{\rm new}_{\mu\nu} =  \frac{(n-2)}{4(n-1)} \Big((g_{\mu\nu} \nabla^2 - \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu)\varphi^2 + (R_{\mu\nu}- {\textstyle \frac 12} g_{\mu\nu} R)\varphi^2\Big) 
$$
the result is the ``new improved'' energy-momentum tensor of C.G.Callan Jr., S.~Coleman, and R.~Jackiw, A new improved energy-momentum tensor,  Annals of Physics {\bf 59} (1970)  42-73. This  differs from the standard one even in flat space where the scalar curvature $R$ is zero. It   has much better-behaved matrix elements even for non-zero masses. The on-shell (i.e using the equations of motion) trace of the new tensor is $m^2\varphi^2$.
Note that you almost always have to use equations of motion to prove conservation laws such as the tracelessness condition. This is the essence of  Noether's theorem.

Thanks, this is quite helpful. I now found out that this improvement is also explained in di Francesco et al's book on conformal field theory.
